# Grails GORM SQL bind param failure with validate()

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I've a strange problem with Grails 2.2.3 and validating a domain object; I've got two database dumps which are as far as I can tell identical;

The error occurs when updating a record and calling validate() with the following error:

```
util.JDBCExceptionReporter  - No value specified for parameter 1
```

I've turned on hibernate SQL logging as well as bind logging.

With the database that doesn't work a get the following logging output:

```
2014-10-22 12:28:06,163 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG hibernate.SQL  - select this_.id as id0_0_, this_.version as version0_0_, this_.birthday as birthday0_0_, this_.cellular as cellular0_0_, this_.city as city0_0_, this_.country as country0_0_, this_.date_created as date7_0_0_, this_.description as descript8_0_0_, this_.email as email0_0_, this_.first_name as first10_0_0_, this_.gender as gender0_0_, this_.house_number as house12_0_0_, this_.identifier as identifier0_0_, this_.is_child as is14_0_0_, this_.is_host as is15_0_0_, this_.is_press as is16_0_0_, this_.is_visitor as is17_0_0_, this_.last_name as last18_0_0_, this_.last_updated as last19_0_0_, this_.latitude as latitude0_0_, this_.longitude as longitude0_0_, this_.phone as phone0_0_, this_.picture as picture0_0_, this_.postal_code as postal24_0_0_, this_.state as state0_0_, this_.street as street0_0_ from person this_ where this_.email=?
2014-10-22 12:28:06,164 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] TRACE sql.BasicBinder  - binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - joe@example.net
2014-10-22 12:28:06,168 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] TRACE sql.BasicExtractor  - found [1414] as column [id0_0_]
2014-10-22 12:28:06,169 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG hibernate.SQL  - select this_.id as id0_0_, this_.version as version0_0_, this_.birthday as birthday0_0_, this_.cellular as cellular0_0_, this_.city as city0_0_, this_.country as country0_0_, this_.date_created as date7_0_0_, this_.description as descript8_0_0_, this_.email as email0_0_, this_.first_name as first10_0_0_, this_.gender as gender0_0_, this_.house_number as house12_0_0_, this_.identifier as identifier0_0_, this_.is_child as is14_0_0_, this_.is_host as is15_0_0_, this_.is_press as is16_0_0_, this_.is_visitor as is17_0_0_, this_.last_name as last18_0_0_, this_.last_updated as last19_0_0_, this_.latitude as latitude0_0_, this_.longitude as longitude0_0_, this_.phone as phone0_0_, this_.picture as picture0_0_, this_.postal_code as postal24_0_0_, this_.state as state0_0_, this_.street as street0_0_ from person this_ where this_.id=?
2014-10-22 12:28:06,172 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] ERROR util.JDBCExceptionReporter  - No value specified for parameter 1
```

With the working database I get the following:

```
2014-10-22 12:23:24,476 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG hibernate.SQL  - select this_.id as id7_0_, this_.version as version7_0_, this_.birthday as birthday7_0_, this_.cellular as cellular7_0_, this_.city as city7_0_, this_.country as country7_0_, this_.date_created as date7_7_0_, this_.description as descript8_7_0_, this_.email as email7_0_, this_.first_name as first10_7_0_, this_.gender as gender7_0_, this_.house_number as house12_7_0_, this_.identifier as identifier7_0_, this_.is_child as is14_7_0_, this_.is_host as is15_7_0_, this_.is_press as is16_7_0_, this_.is_visitor as is17_7_0_, this_.last_name as last18_7_0_, this_.last_updated as last19_7_0_, this_.latitude as latitude7_0_, this_.longitude as longitude7_0_, this_.phone as phone7_0_, this_.picture as picture7_0_, this_.postal_code as postal24_7_0_, this_.state as state7_0_, this_.street as street7_0_ from person this_ where this_.email=?
2014-10-22 12:23:24,477 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] TRACE sql.BasicBinder  - binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - joe@example.net
2014-10-22 12:23:24,480 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] TRACE sql.BasicExtractor  - found [1414] as column [id7_0_]
2014-10-22 12:23:24,499 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG hibernate.SQL  - select this_.id as id7_0_, this_.version as version7_0_, this_.birthday as birthday7_0_, this_.cellular as cellular7_0_, this_.city as city7_0_, this_.country as country7_0_, this_.date_created as date7_7_0_, this_.description as descript8_7_0_, this_.email as email7_0_, this_.first_name as first10_7_0_, this_.gender as gender7_0_, this_.house_number as house12_7_0_, this_.identifier as identifier7_0_, this_.is_child as is14_7_0_, this_.is_host as is15_7_0_, this_.is_press as is16_7_0_, this_.is_visitor as is17_7_0_, this_.last_name as last18_7_0_, this_.last_updated as last19_7_0_, this_.latitude as latitude7_0_, this_.longitude as longitude7_0_, this_.phone as phone7_0_, this_.picture as picture7_0_, this_.postal_code as postal24_7_0_, this_.state as state7_0_, this_.street as street7_0_ from person this_ where this_.email=?
2014-10-22 12:23:24,500 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] TRACE sql.BasicBinder  - binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - joe@example.net
2014-10-22 12:23:24,503 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] TRACE sql.BasicExtractor  - found [1414] as column [id7_0_]
```

The difference is that the working version queries two times for the entry with an email address as search parameter whereas the broken version tries to query by ID the second time and fails to bind an ID.

Any suggestion where to look for the error? What to try in terms of debugging it better?

Thanks
Michael

EDIT:

GORM class Person.groovy

```
class Person {

    enum Gender {
        MALE,FEMALE,FAMILY,NO_GENDER
    }

    Date dateCreated
    Date lastUpdated

    Set identifiers

    String firstName
    String lastName
    String email
    String phone
    String cellular
    String street
    String houseNumber
    String postalCode
    String city
    String state
    String country

    Date birthday
    Gender gender = Gender.NO_GENDER

    Double latitude
    Double longitude

    String picture
    String description

    static hasOne = [paymentInformation: PaymentInformation]

    static hasMany = [identifiers: String, children: ChildParent, parents: ChildParent, guests: ChildHost, visitorCalls: VisitorCall, comments: PersonComment, flags: PersonFlag, sentMessages: Message, receivedMessages: Message, romperRoomBookings: RomperRoomBooking, payments: Payment]

    static mappedBy = [children: 'parent', parents: 'child', sentMessages: 'sender']

    static constraints = {
        firstName nullable: false, blank: false
        lastName nullable: false, blank: false
        email nullable: false, blank: false, email: true, unique: true
        phone nullable: true, blank: false
        cellular nullable: true, blank: false
        street nullable: true, blank: false
        houseNumber nullable: true, blank: false
        postalCode nullable: true, blank: false
        city nullable: true, blank: false
        state nullable: true, blank: false
        country nullable: true, blank: false

        latitude nullable: true
        longitude nullable: true

        birthday nullable: true
        gender nullable: true

        picture nullable: true, blank: false
        description nullable: true, blank: false

        paymentInformation nullable: true, unique: true
    }

    static mapping = {
        description type: 'text'

        paymentInformation lazy: false

        flags lazy: false
    }
}
```

And the controller where the error occurs is

```
def person = Person.get(id)
if (person) {
    def personInput = JSON.parse(request)
    if (personInput) {
        def gecodingAddress = googleGeocodingService.geocode(personInput.street,personInput.houseNumber,personInput.postalCode,personInput.city,personInput.state ? personInput.state : null,personInput.country ? personInput.country : "Germany")
        if (gecodingAddress) {
            person.firstName = personInput.firstName
            person.lastName = personInput.lastName
            person.street = gecodingAddress.street
            person.houseNumber = gecodingAddress.houseNumber
            person.postalCode = gecodingAddress.postalCode
            person.city = gecodingAddress.city
            person.state = gecodingAddress.state
            person.country = gecodingAddress.country
            person.latitude = gecodingAddress.lat
            person.longitude = gecodingAddress.lon
            person.email = JSONObject.NULL.equals(personInput.email) || personInput.email?.isEmpty() ? null : personInput.email
            person.phone = JSONObject.NULL.equals(personInput.phone) || personInput.phone?.isEmpty() ? null : personInput.phone
            person.cellular = JSONObject.NULL.equals(personInput.cellular) || personInput.cellular?.isEmpty() ? null : personInput.cellular
            person.dateCreated = new Date(personInput.dateCreated)
            if (person.validate()) {
                if (person.save(flush: true)) {
                    render(person as JSON)
                }
                else {
                    render(status: 500)
                }
            }
            else {
                log.warn("validate failed!")
                person.errors.allErrors.each {
                    log.warn(it)
                }
                render(status: 400)
            }
        }
        else {
            render(status: 500)
        }
    }
    else {
        render(status: 400)
    }
}
else {
    render(status: 404)
}
```

The person.validate() call fails, it doesn't even make it to the person.save()

Comment: I added the GORM class as well as the relevant part from the controller

Comment: What do you mean by "I've got two database dumps which are as far as I can tell identical"?

Comment: One is from my development system, the other from is from the remote instance which has been set up using the mysql dump from my development machine; in order to but the differences in the two systems down to a minimum I once again did a mysql dump on the remote machine and created another database on my local machine; the result is that only the original version from my local machine works, the reimported one from the remote machine doesn't work and results in the above mentioned error.